# How to append a website to a browser's history with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history, html5-history

I'm making a website and we're switching our domain. I want it so that when they log on to the website, it adds a new website with the new domain to their browser history.

I've already tried making a hidden `<iframe>` and I'm out of ideas.

The main browser they are using is chrome, so cross-browser is not a concern.

But limitations are that we are not allowed to load the page / open it in a new tab/window.

Comment: You need to read up on `pushState`

Comment: if I don't go to `xyz.com`, I don't expect `xyz.com` in my history :p Why would you want to infect someone's history with sites they don't go to?

Comment: Why aren't you just redirecting them to the new domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HTML5 History api. To push to history, you’d use:

`history.pushState(null, null, 'http://example.com');`

You’ll probably run into some browser issues though.

For more info check this out: https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will throw a `SecurityException` if you aren't on the http://example.com domain already.

Comment: @gyre Yeah, but SO wouldn't let me use `xyz.com` and said to use `example.com` instead

Comment: I meant that this code cannot be used to push history entries across domains, which is what OP seems to be requesting.